# Initializing class variables in nested classes

Tags: c++, class

I'm new to C++ classes, and I have some questions about nested classes.

What I Know

1. classes in C++ are set of variables and functions set by 'private' by default.
2. when you create a class, an object is created.
3. I understand the basic concepts of constructors.

I know that I can make 'classes' as an variable in an another 'class', also known as **nested class**, but I really can't figure out how it is done exactly. If I create an nested class, does it create object itself, and objects from the class variables inside the nested class?

I'm having problems initializing class variables in nested class using constructors.

**For example**

```
class Point {
int xpos;
int ypos; 
}
```

Let's say that I  created a class containing 2 int variables.

```
class Rectangle {
Point upLeft;
Point lowRight;
}
```

Then, I created a Rectangle class having 2 'Point class' as variables.

```
Rectangle rec1;
```

Then, I created an object **rec1**.

How can I initialize the 2 xpos and 2ypos using **constructors** **in Rectangle Class?**

Comment: You will [find the answer to your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Grab your text book and look up "Member Initializer List".

Comment: "Nested class" means something entirely different in C++, which you're not doing here.  What you have is "members with class type".  "When you create a class, an object is created" is confusing and not true.  I think what you meant there was "When you define a variable with class type, an object is created."  (Note that "object" is also a technical term which is not limited to class types!  Variables with fundamental types like `int` or `double`, pointer types, or array types all name objects too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add a constructor, here is a simple example:

```
class Point {
public:
    Point(int x, int y) : xpos(x), ypos(y) {}
private:
    int xpos;
    int ypos; 
};


class Rectangle {
public:
    Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) : upLeft(Point(x1, y1)), lowRight(Point(x2, y2)) {}
private:
    Point upLeft;
    Point lowRight;
};
```

Comment: Note that it isn't necessary to construct a temporary `Point` prior to constructing the points in the `Rectangle`, as you can do `upLeft(x1, y1)` directly rather than `upLeft(Point(x1, y1))`. (It doesn't matter for a simple case like the one here, but for larger objects, or objects without move or copy constructors it could be important).